# Unknown error when trying to pass parameters to the Http Post method using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement a product information window in which there is a partial view responsible for displaying the quantity of product in stock. The quantity of the product in stock is represented by a separate linked table "productCount". I need to add the product quantity without reloading the view and reload only a partial view. To do this, I decided to use jQuery AJAX. The solution method was based on the materials of this answer: "[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763481/updating-view-with-model-changes-via-ajax-post-mvc3)". But I ran into problems unknown to me.: Firstly, I have difficulty getting the value from the input field, and secondly, when I try to execute the function, a message unknown to me appears
Script code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function addQuantityClicked() {
            var Url = '@Url.Action("QuantityAdd", "Home")';
            $.ajax({
                url: Url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: { idProduct: @Model.Product.Id, quantity: alert($("#qnt").val) }
            })
        }
</script>
```

```html
@using vp_server.Models.ViewModels
@model vp_server.Models.ViewModels.ProductViewsTransactions
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <label>The quantity at the moment: @Model.Count</label>
        <form>
        <label>Entrance:</label>
            <input type="number" id="qnt" name="quantity" />
            <input type="button" onclick="addQuantityClicked()" id="changeButton" value="Add" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
<script src="~/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried to use `document.getElementById("qnt").value` but`.value` is not defined by the code editor

[Strange message when trying to execute the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyJd0.png)
The code of the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> QuantityAdd(int idProduct, int quantity)
{
    using (VapeshopContext db = new VapeshopContext())
    {
        ProductCount? productCount = db.ProductCounts.Where(pc => pc.ProductId == idProduct).FirstOrDefault();
        if (productCount != null)
        {
            productCount.Count += quantity;
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return PartialView();
    }            
}
```

I deleted the alert, although now the message does not appear, but the method also does not respond

I partially changed the JS code and removed .ajax to test the script and left a test message in `.alert`. The message is output, but if you return `.ajax`, nothing happens and even the message is output to `.alert`
New JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnPost").click(function () {
            alert("Test")
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url = "/Home/QuantityAdd",
                data: { "idProduct": @Model.Product.Id, "quantity": $("#qnt").val() }
            })
        })
    })
</script>

<script src="~/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Remove the alert. `.val` is a function you call it with `()`. `$("#qnt").val()`

Comment: @Musa I deleted the `alert`, although now the message does not appear, but the method also does not respond

Comment: Have you try   `data: { "idProduct": 1, "quantity":2) }` ?

Comment: @QingGuo Yes, unfortunately, it doesn't work either. Maybe I'm using the wrong libraries?

Comment: Have a try : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function addQuantityClicked() {
            var Url = '@Url.Action("QuantityAdd", "Home")';
            $.ajax({
                url: Url,
                type: 'POST',
                
                data: { "idProduct": 1, "quantity":2 }
            });
        }
</script>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: This may sound strange, but I tried your solution and nothing happened, the method did not get a value. Perhaps there is some hidden problem with the software

Comment: Hi@vhhs , you can try to create a new project and test my solution.

Comment: Yes, it worked in the new project! Thank you very much!